# How to reduce pdf file size using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Like the title said: How to reduce pdf file size using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat XI Pro actually has a feature to reduce pdf file size:

Go to `File` > `Save As Other...` > `Reduced Sized PDF`
[image: reduce pdf file size]

I found out this feature [a while ago](https://superuser.com/a/1308015/525666). It's pretty effective, My 92MB pdf file (contains scanned images) is reduced to 16MB (Note that the reduce size depends on each pdf, maybe your case better or worse than mine)